# Phone validation not working - jQuery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to use Phone validation in jQuery validation plugin, other validations such as required and email are working, but the phoneUS validation is not working as shown in this example: http://jqueryvalidation.org/phoneUS-method

Here's the code am using:

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        txtHomePhone:{
        phoneUS: true
        },

      }
        });
```

It doesn't show any error, just not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the phoneUS method, you must include the additional methods library, in addition to the JQuery Validator and JQuery libraries.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3pgzcLw/1/)